# DateTimeKind doesn't change any part of the date between UTC/Local/Unspecified

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

[image: Hello]

How this is possible? I expected at least 1 hour difference between UTC and local

The thing came up while querying cosmosDB on azure in visual studio with C#

Comment: It's always the same point in time and DateTime internally stores its date/time as (UTC) ticks. To see a difference you would need to call `ToLocalTime` or `ToUniversalTime` to switch timezones between local and universal. The former will change the time to local time when the kind to is UTC or Unspecified, the latter will change the time to universal time when the kind is Local or Unspecified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per the [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), DateTimeKind Enumeration Specifies whether
>   a DateTime object represents a local time, a Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC), or is not specified as either local time or UTC.

That means, It won't give you the converted time but, The members of the DateTimeKind enumeration are used in conversion operations between local time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), but not in comparison or arithmetic operations.

[image]